# Excel chart not correctly reflecting data

Tags: excel, time, scada

I have two sets (August and February) of SCADA data that contain a time stamp and a tank level. The tank level is on the y axis, and the date/time on the x axis. I am trying to display this as a smooth line, scatter plot. The February data displays correctly in the chart, but the August data does not. It looks very irregular, and it shows an odd date range (from January of 1900 to March of 1934!). The odd thing as that the data looks the same; although the August data doesn't appear to automatically assign AM/PM to the time stamp. Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: We can't really see what kind of data it is or what type of chart you plotted.  I would assume its being plotted as a line chart and not x-y scatter.  For the date range it is likely just showing the numbers 1 (Jan 1, 1900) through ~12500 (March 1934) so I would guess its not getting the x-axis data correctly.  Make sure it is an xy scatter, and make sure the dates are proper excel dates and not text.

Comment: It is a smooth line, scatter plot, as I stated in my description. I agree that it's not getting the x-asix data correctly, but I don't know why. The data for each chart comes from .txt files with basically the same format, and I made sure that each cell was formatted correctly for time. It is very mysterious!

Comment: Are they proper dates (not just text that looks like dates).  Try selecting 1 and press **ctrl+shift+1** to format it as a number.  If it doesn't change you have a text string that excel isn't interpreting correctly.

Comment: The dates were not formatted correctly. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: [···](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295912/which-option-shall-i-use-to-close-questions-with-answers-in-comments)